# access the name in the Name Manager with a variable cell

Tags: excel

I'm looking to access the name in the Name Manager that I've already created by a Variable Cell.

For example :

- I have multiple data set already name `US10Y`, `CAD10Y`, `AUD10Y`...
- I have Cell H4 and Cell I4 that contain the name of the country

  ```
  Cell H4 = US
  Cell I4 = CAD
  ```

These cells need to be variable so I can put any country I want

I want to calculate the correlation between `US10Y` and `CAD10Y` (that are already set in the manager name)

I tried `Correl( H4 & "10Y", I4 &"10Y")` but Excel don't understand that I referred to some pre-name Range.

I will need to do the same with Graph Series and ...

Comment: Look at `INDIRECT()`

Comment: And then avoid using `INDIRECT` (because it makes for bad model design).

Comment: Use Indirect then Avoid it, Im not sure I understand